# Qual versão do PIP devo usar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

A minha atual dúvida é: obrigatoriamente devo usar pip3 para Python3.x ou posso usar também pip sem nenhum problema? Quais são as diferenças entre as versões do pip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Obrigatoriamente devo usar pip3 para Python3.x ou posso usar também pip sem nenhum problema?

[A versão do `pip` trabalha com qualquer versão de Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), em teoria. Normalmente o Python já vem com uma versão do pip pré-configurada para o ambiente.

> Quais são as diferenças entre as versões do pip?

As mesmas que de um software *open source* regular: os recursos e maturidade do código quanto a bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem Python 2x e Python3x, normalmente você acaba tendo pip e pip3. A diferença é que pip instala as bilbiotecas no Python 2 e pip3 instala as bilbiotecas no Python 3 ou no seu virtualenv.

Se você só tem o Python 3 instalado ou está dentro de um virtualenv, você só vai ter um pip, e ele instala as bilbiotecas no Python 3.

Para saber qual pip está apontando para qual instalação do python, vc pode usar:

```
pip -V
```